# GEO IP на JS - возможно ли?

Tags: javascript, ip, геолокация, geoip

Добрый день. Раньше реализовывал определение страны по IP на PHP. Сейчас сайт на чистом HTML. Есть ли базы IP адресов для JS ? Необходимо определять лишь страну.

Comment: Есть просто базы адресов (гугл в помощь), а на чём к ним обращаться - дело десятое.

Answer (score 2):

Можете воспользоватся  ресурсом `ipinfo.io`. Приведу пример по JQuery

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
    var IP = data.ip;
    getCountry(IP);
    });




   function  getCountry(IP){
   var country = '';
j.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/' + IP, function(data){
    country = data.country;
    console.log(country);
});
    }
```

Comment: Что будет, если хуквери помрёт? Или она как Элвис?

Comment: @Other, а что будет, если JS помрёт? Или он как Элвис?

Comment: Нет, он как битлы. Я к тому, что в тегах нет хуквери, реализуется ванилькой легко... Диагноз: хуквери зависимость в тяжёлой форме.

Comment: @Other никакой 'хуквери' зависимости нет, это простой пример, не думаю что есть смысл цеплятся за мелочи в 'репертуаре - нет такого тега', реализация данного ответа могут быть в разной форме, и это хорошо т.к пользователи могут использовать любые методы решения.Филосовский смысл возникновение Jquery именно в том чтобы сделать код более приятным и коротким, это называется - развитие. С такой же логикой можно пинать людей которые зажигают костёр спичками - "зачем вам спички? вы же можете зажечь огонь посредством палки и сухой травы , методом трения рук...

Comment: @Arsen, без тега "Бомбануло", писать такие опусы нельзя :)

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не задействовать онлайн-сервис, коих море?
Пример:

```js
function test(result){
  console.info(`
Ваш IP: ${result.geoplugin_request}
Страна: [${result.geoplugin_countryCode}] ${result.geoplugin_countryName}
Местоположение: ${result.geoplugin_region}, ${result.geoplugin_city} [${result.geoplugin_latitude}x${result.geoplugin_longitude}]
`);
}

document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=test';
  
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

```html
<input type='button' id='send' value='Узнать обо мне' />
```